# Location Of Canon Paper ICC Profiles On Mac El-Capitan

Tags: canon, printer, icc-profile

I've just set up a new iMac and have installed the driver for my Canon Pixma Pro 100 printer. It seems that Canon no longer offers a separate download of their ICC paper profiles, but that they are installed when the driver is installed. I can see all the Canon Pro paper profiles in the printer dialogue, along with any other ICC profiles I have placed in `Library/ColorSync/Profiles`.

However in the print dialogue in Lightroom, the Canon paper profiles don't show up. It only displays profiles in `Library/ColorSync/Profiles`, and the Canon profiles are not located there.

Where can I find these profiles? They must be somewhere on my machine as they *are* available in the print dialogue so it seems that they were installed to an unknown location when I installed the driver. If I knew where they were I could add them to the ColorSync Profiles folder so that they are available in Lightroom.

Comment: Have you tried an old fashioned research for *.icc files?

Comment: Scratch my previous, I changed my mind...

Comment: @Oliver Yes I did, but didn't seem to pick up any of the .icc files.

Answer (score 1):

Let me help you a bit for future... On a UNIX-based system, there's a handy little utility known as "find" which can be used to search the file system for patterns. So, for example:

```
find /Library/ -name "*.icc" -print
```

This will find all files with the extension .icc inside the system Library folder and print them to the console. For more details, in a terminal:

```
man find
```

If you want to put the results in a text file so you can more easily look at them, then:

```
find /Library/ -name "*.icc" -print > ~/Desktop/icc.txt
```

Hopefully that helps. You might need to use sudo to see in some directories, just put that at the beginning of the command followed by a space.

```
sudo find ...
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I'd searched with finder, but it didn't seem to show anything, probably because the files were in Library and inside some kind of zipped file found at `Library//Printers/Canon/BJPrinter/Resources/ICCProfiles/PRO100series.canonicc` (Right click it and choose 'show package contents' to drill down to `Contents/Resources/*`). Strangely though, the command you supplied failed to list any of the .icc profiles found in the ColorSync directory.

Comment: @Pedr - The "find" command isn't Finder. :) As for ColorSync files, they list for me, but your permissions in the file system may vary.

Comment: I did find them using terminal and your command. I was just noting that I had previously searched with Finder.

Comment: An alternative for the 'terminal-wary' is [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) - freeware, which will search hidden locations unlike Spotlight  [though it's slower because it's not indexed]

Answer (score 1):

Though @John's answer is fantastic for finding all `*.icc` files, the problem with the Canon driver's `*.icc` profiles is that they are embedded in a `*.canonicc package`, as @Undistraction points out in his comment.

On macOS Mojave, re-installing the printer driver from Canon's site did not install the ICC profiles in a way that allowed me to use them from Lightroom natively. (Canon Print Studio Pro works completely outside of the normal Lightroom printing dialog and is *not* a good solution for me).

Following @Undistraction's instructions, I opened a finder window to `/Library/Printers/Canon/BJPrinter/Resources/ICCProfiles` and right-clicked on `PRO100series.canonicc` and selected **Show Package Contents** from the menu. Inside are `.icc` profiles for Canon papers for the Pro-100. I'm not sure if these were left over from a previous driver install, but the were what I was looking for.

I copied all of them and pasted to `~/Library/Library/ColorSync/Profiles` and they are now available in Lightroom to use when printing.

Canon does offer a separate download if ICC Profiles for Art Paper on their [Support Page](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/professional-large-format-printers/professional-inkjet-printers/pro-100?subtab=downloads-software), but those do not contain any papers made by Canon.